# Склонение имен  собственных

Tags: топонимика, ономастика

Какое окончание будет в творительном падеже сущ., обозначающего географическое название - Лиозно

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего надо посмотреть в каком-нибудь справочнике географических названий, склоняем ли этот топоним. У меня, увы, нет такого под рукой.

Но если речь идет о населенном пункте в Белоруссии, то полагаю его склоняющимся по общим правилам: *"рядом с Лиозном".* Оснований для формы *"Лиозным"* тут нет никаких, это название - не фамилия и даже не от фамилии образовано. Впрочем, в последнем случае все равно было бы "-ом": "Рядом с Пушкином" (городом).